# Does Swift compile to native code?

Tags: swift

Simple question really, however there doesn't seem to be a straight answer in the [current developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html).

Does Swift compile to machine language (i.e. assembly), or does it compile to some intermediary form that then runs on a virtual machine?

(I suspect it does, but being unfamiliar with development in Apple's world it is not clear to me like it may be to someone who is.)

Comment: In Linux you can compile to native by [`swiftc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103300/compile-swift-code-to-native-executable-for-linux/34103362#34103362)

Comment: swift compiler in swift docs https://swift.org/swift-compiler/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it compiles to machine language by way of LLVM Bitcode and, as @connor said, runs on top of the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: OK and does it "compiles to machine language by way of llvm" at run time or ahead of time?

Comment: llvm bit-code is just the intermediate format that's used by the llvm collection of compilers.  It allows all of them to use a common code generator.  Translation is swift->bit-code->assembler->machine language.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, this is what allows the swift repl to work, it compiles to llvm bit-code and that bit-code can be run by a VM in the swift repl (or Xcode playground)

Comment: OK to the answer it seems is: both! :)

Comment: @markmnl I guess you can say it can be both.  When you build an application, that application is compiled to machine code.

Comment: The Ars Technica article on Yosemite describes the compilation process.  It mentions converting to the Swift Intermediate Language (SIL) as the first step.  As others have said, it ultimately generates machine code through LLVM.
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/10/os-x-10-10/22/

Comment: Swift does not run on Objective-C's runtime. It has its own runtime. I can use the Objective-C runtime when using Objective-C-inheriting classes, but Swift does not run "on top of" Objective-C. This is not to be mistaken for a virtual machine; Swift compiles to native code.

Comment: @mattdipasquale That Swift can run on devices without the Objective-C runtime is proof that Swift does not run on top of Objective-C. This is the case when you install Swift on Linux. Even on computers with Objective-C, Swift does not use Objective-C at all unless you're using classes written in Objective-C.

Comment: OK. Thank you, @rsmoz. :-)

Comment: Some feature of Swift use the keyword @objc which compiles with the Objective-C runtime, but pure Swift is compile through LLVM to pseudo-machine code like the Clang does with objective C. Then both output are linked together to make the program run

Answer (score 28):

Swift not only compiles to native machine code but it has also been [designed specifically for it](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001948.html). Unlike e.g. Java which has been designed specifically as a JITed language. By that I mean Swift achieves best performance with ahead of time compilation while Java benefits most from JITing.

There are many reasons for these design choices but among them is that Swift has a much bigger scope than managed languages like Java. It is supposed to work on both desktop computers and phones with more restricted hardware. You can use Swift as a systems programming language unlike say C#, Java or Python because it has little runtime requirements and allow fairly detailed control of memory. So in theory one should be able to build an OS kernel with Swift which would be difficult with say Java.

Comment: Java was originally targeted toward embedded systems, not the desktop. JVM and JRE are decoupled; this means that it doesn't need to use the 20-200MB runtime that comes traditionally with Java on the desktop. Java VMs have long run on microcontrollers (uJ, Javelin) in the sub-$5 performance range. Also there is a java OS kernel called jNode. I'll digress though that a precompiled program such as that by Swift could be more energy-conservative on battery-critical devices like phones  compared to *VM platforms. It gets more complicated when processors like Jazelle directly-execute java bytecode.

Comment: I am aware of this and my reply probably could add some nuance. There is of course a rich history of VM like languages running on embedded hardware. E.g. Erlang is used on telecoms equipment. However I think it depends on application. Typically these uses are not CPU intensive and it wont work for all cases. E.g. when controlling a stepper motor from an AVR micro-controller you want complete control over timing. You don't want some garbage collector to suddenly jump in. We have already seen this problem with Android games.

Answer (score 13):

Swift, just like objective-c compiles to native code using [llvm](http://www.llvm.org)

A good explanation can be found in [Apple's top secret Swift language grew from work to sustain Objective C, which it now aims to replace](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/06/04/apples-top-secret-swift-language-grew-from-work-to-sustain-objective-c-which-it-now-aims-to-replace)

From that article, talking about Swift

> The compiler is optimized for performance, and the language is
>   optimized for development, without compromising on either.

Comment: when you say "compile" do you mean at compile time or run time?

Comment: At compile time, swift code is compiled to llvm bit-code as @David said.

Comment: Yes I saw that quote but it just sounds like whimsical marketing and doesn't give any actual technical detail - however you have now answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Swift, like Objective-C, is compiled to machine code that runs on the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Objective-C, but you say _runtime_ which sounds like a virtual machine interpreting intermediary byte code, i.e. Swift does not compile to native code?

Comment: Well it's a library, not really a virtual machine. Basically your code calls on the obj-c runtime to do object oriented stuff. All of the code including the obj-c runtime is compiled down to machine code.

Comment: here's some more info too: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html

Comment: Swift most certainly does not "[run] on the Objective-C runtime". It *uses* the Objective-C runtime for classes and protocols (those specifically marked `@objc`), but features it's own runtime for about everything else.

Comment: @Connor, based on your answer and your comment, should you not say then ***"[...] that runs along side the Objective-C runtime library"***? This would be more clear than ***"on the Objective-C runtime"***, which seems like it is "managed" by or VM-like.