# String parser for Swift?

Tags: parsing, swift

I'm working on a project that **draws functions on a plane** (Similar to Apple's Grapher utility).

I'have already compiled this app few months ago in Obj-C, and ***was running clean and fast***.

With Swift, I changed a bit the scheme of the app, but I'm still using [**CGMathParser**](http://apptree.net/parser.htm), a great collection of classes to manipulate and **evaluate strings like** `y=sin(x)` or `y=log(tan(x))`

However **the app is now slow and laggy**, and I'm thinking that the reason hides in the fact that I'm **mixing Swift with Obj-C**.

*Do you know* if there is any kind of **parser** already optimized **for Swift** that will be fast enough?

Comment: I think that Swift should work very well with Obj-C. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052386/does-swift-compile-to-native-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift compiler enforces bounds checks and various other 'safety' features. If you compile with the `-Ofast` option these checks are removed, which typically makes your app run a lot faster.

[image]

Comment: This now appears to have been changed in Xcode 8.3.2