# Compile Swift code to native executable for Linux

Tags: linux, swift

I've installed Swift lang for Linux (Ubuntu) and it works fine. For example:

```
print("Hello World")
```

To run it:

```
./swift hi.swift
```

My question is, is it possible to generate a native executable code for it? How?

Answer (score 9):

Listing the executable files in the Swift directory, it has `swiftc`. It generates a native executable binary by command:

```
swiftc hi.swift -o hi
./hi
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `swiftc`, one can also generate native executables by using the Swift build system, which is described at

https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-build-system

Using the build system, one can easily build native executables from multiple source files, while swiftc is a convenient way to build an executable from a single source file.

Please note that you also need to install Clang if you want to create native executables with Swift.  Clang is not needed to run the swift command interactively or to run a .swift file.  Interestingly, installing GCC (including g++) and creating symlink clang++ to  g++ does allow swiftrc to build an executable.  This also enables `swift build` to work.  At least it is true for very simple programs.  However, this is not a "blessed" way.  Apple docs at swift.org say that Clang is needed.